# tmux on linux server

Tags: linux, tmux

I'm trying to set up tmux on linux server to do shared sessions.
I'have copied my .tmux.conf on the server.
On my mac i have tmux 1.6

on the server, some of the option in my config don't work.
is there a way to find out which version of tmux is installed?

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
$ tmux -V     
    tmux 1.6
```

Older versions of tmux are indeed buggy. I've never tried shared sessions.

Comment: Shared sessions are actually the default in tmux, as long as both users have the correct permissions on the session files in `/tmp`.

Comment: ah! i tried tmux --version and tmux -v but not -V.

Comment: FYI, tmux 1.3 and earlier also lack -V. I'm not sure when -V was introduced (1.4? 1.5?)